# Can I easily convert windows store desktop app to universal or phone app?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

As we know there is posibility to create three types of windows 8.1 applications: desktop, phone, and universal. So, I have a win 8.1 application which was obviusly built for desktop, but I wanna change its type to phone or universal, how can I do it?

Comment: You'll need to rewrite large portions of it more than likely. What type of desktop application is it?

Comment: It is a kind of empty template project written on javascript. Thence I want to convert it, if it is not too hard.

Comment: A desktop app that was JavaScript? I don't understand. The basic answer, is "no." You can't easily convert from one to the other. The UI is different. The UI patterns are different. The platform is different along with the capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are moving towards cross platform development.  I recommend using a java base library like libgdx.  My app runs on Windows,Macs,Android phones/tablets, and Iphones/Ipads.  Its all one code base but for many different platforms.  I've very happy with the results.  I'm mainly a c# dev so there was a small learning curve moving to java.  I dont know if there is something similar that will run on windows phone.  Good luck.